# monitor service for "failure"

Tags: python, scripting

I'm developing a script which monitors a service for failure and launches another a different action depending on if failure is present or not.

I require a python script to monitor the output from a python program "monitor-services" and parsing the output search for an occurance of the word "failure". If present, the script should return with a true value, and run for a maxiumum of 30 seconds returning false if no occurance of "failure" occurs.

Sample output returned from "monitor-services":

```
{Device} [/device/xxx] Networks = dbus.Array([dbus.ObjectPath('/device/xxx/xxx'), dbus.ObjectPath('/device/00242b2e41b6/hidden')], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)
{Service} [/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_wep] State = association
{Profile} [/profile/default] Services = dbus.Array([dbus.ObjectPath('/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_wep'), dbus.ObjectPath('/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_rsn')], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)
{Manager} [/] Services = dbus.Array([dbus.ObjectPath('/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_wep'), dbus.ObjectPath('/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_rsn')], signature=dbus.Signature('o'), variant_level=1)
{Service} [/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_wep] **failure**
{Service} [/profile/default/wifi_xxx_managed_wep] State = idle
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[edit] A failure is likely to occur with 30 seconds or so of the action triggering the script, hence the script is required to terminate after 30 seconds. [/edit]

Comment: This seems a very straightforward thing (at least in Perl, just use "grep" function). Why are you using Python? Can you use some language you're more familiar with or that presents easy facilities (e.g. Perl)?

Comment: Sounds like this possible could be be a job for supervisord. Or not. But still. http://supervisord.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

data = Popen(["monitor-services"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

sys.exit("failure" in data)
```

This does everything you want, except for the 30s wait (which I don't understand). Notice that it returns 0 if failure is not found, 1 if it is found, according to the shell conventions (i.e. 0 is success, non-zero is failure).

Comment: Yup, this works. Thanks for your response!

Re: 30s limit - an error is only going to occur in the first 30 seconds after the script has been initialized. However threads & timers can easily solve this.